# "unsupported operand types(s)" error message

Tags: python, string

Program that pulls in donation information and processes it to produce a
report for the user.

```py
def percent_of_target(donation, goal):
    """returns a float representing the percentage of the overall goal that 
    is contributed by the given donation"""
    result = donation / goal
    result_percentage = result * 100
    return result_percentage

def categorise_donations(donations, campaign_goal):
    """return a list of tuples with the first value of the tuple being the 
    amount donated and the second value being the category for that donation"""
    my_list = []
    for donation in donations:
        percentage = percent_of_target(donation, campaign_goal)
        # append to list and continue
    return my_list

def main():
    """Gets information from the user and then prints a report using functions
    that you have written through this quiz"""
    input_donations = []
    goal_amount = input('Campaign goal: ')
    print('Enter the donations received.')
    continue_program = True
    while continue_program == True:
        donation = input('Amount donated? ')
        if donation.isalpha() == True:
            if donation.lower() == 'q':
                continue_program = False
        else:
            input_donations.append(donation)
    donations = categorise_donations(input_donations, goal_amount)
    # print the table and exit

main()
```

OUTPUT in shell:

```
Python 3.8.4 (v3.8.4:dfa645a65e, Jul 13 2020, 10:45:06) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[evaluate Ass2(q6).py]
Campaign goal: 1000.00
Enter the donations received.
Amount donated? 10.00
Amount donated? 100.00
Amount donated? 1001.00
Amount donated? Q
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/oscarevans/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Ass2(q6).py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/oscarevans/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Ass2(q6).py", line 98, in <module>
    donations = categorise_donations(input_donations, goal_amount)
  File "/Users/oscarevans/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Ass2(q6).py", line 50, in <module>
    percentage = percent_of_target(donation, campaign_goal)
  File "/Users/oscarevans/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Ass2(q6).py", line 41, in <module>
    result = donation / goal
builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Notes:

- the function is meant to exit the while loop and stop accepting donations when a 'Q' or 'q' is entered as input to "amount donated?"
- The program is meant to print a table of inputted donation values and categories given the amount donated.

Answer (score 1):

Your donation values (and goal) are all strings. You probably should be converting them into a numeric data type immediately, once you're sure you haven't seen the `'q'` input that tells you to quit early.

Try something like this:

```
goal_amount = float(input('Campaign goal: '))    # convert to float
print('Enter the donations received.')
continue_program = True
while continue_program == True:
    donation = input('Amount donated? ')
    if donation.isalpha() == True:
        if donation.lower() == 'q':
            continue_program = False
    else:
        input_donations.append(float(donation))  # here too
```